# How to get the directory git detail from repo in GitPython?

Tags: python, git, gitpython

I would like to get the number of commit of a directory(called module) from a repo(project) in GitPython.

```
> print("before",modulePath) 
> repo = Repo(modulePath)                    
> print(len(list(repo.iter_commits())))
```

When I'm trying to print the directory amount of commits, It says the repo is not a valid git Repo.

> - before /home/user/project/module
> - git.exc.InvalidGitRepositoryError: /home/user/project/**module**

Any help or idea would be welcome :)
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an example code from one of my old projects (not open, so no repository links):

```
def parse_commit_log(repo, *params):
    commit = {}
    try:
        log = repo.git.log(*params).split("\n")
    except git.GitCommandError:
        return

    for line in log:
        if line.startswith("    "):
            if not 'message' in commit:
                commit['message'] = ""
            else:
                commit['message'] += "\n"
            commit['message'] += line[4:]
        elif line:
            if 'message' in commit:
                yield commit
                commit = {}
            else:
                field, value = line.split(None, 1)
                commit[field.strip(":")] = value
    if commit:
        yield commit
```

**Explanation:**

The function expects instance of `Repo` and same parameters you would pass to `git log` command. So, usage in your case could look like this:

```
repo = git.Repo('project_path')
commits = list(parse_commit_log(repo, 'module_dir'))
```

Internally, `repo.git.log` is calling `git log` command. Its output looks sort of like this:

```
commit <commit1 sha>
Author: User <username@email.tld>
Date:   Sun Apr 7 17:08:31 2019 -0400

    Commit1 message

commit <commit2 sha>
Author: User2 <username2@email.tld>
Date:   Sun Apr 7 17:08:31 2019 -0400

    Commit2 message
```

`parse_commit_log` parses this output and yields commit messages. You need to add few more lines to get commit sha, author and date, but it should not be too hard.